How to Finish Current Version of Journey in Journey Builder with no new entries
In Journey Builder, I need to stop new entries into the current version of a journey but allow contacts already in the journey to finish.
Entry Source is a Data Extension triggered by a schedule (not automation).
Is the only way to handle this by creating a new version with a dummy DE and activating it to put the current version into "Finishing" status? Are there other best practices for this scenario?
Thanks!

You are indeed correct. Having a journey in Finishing status will allow contacts currently in the journey to progress as normal, but new contacts will not be admitted - regardless of what type of entry event you have.
